# Reading an int from a json file

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python and I am trying to get a ton of user info from my website and save the usergroups that each person has

I've been able to save the response to json but I cannot figure out how to read a in that is returned

### My json File

```py
{
    "pagination": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 9,
        "per_page": 20,
        "shown": 20,
        "total": 173
    },
```

I don't want to show too much since there are emails, etc. saved in my file.

Specifically, I am looking to save the value for "total"

### Attempt

```
with open(pathFile) as json_file:

    # read json file line by line
    for line in json_file.readlines():

        # create python dict from json object
        json_dict = json.loads(line)

        # check if "body" (lowercased) contains any of the keywords
        if any(keyword in json_dict["total"].lower() for keyword in keywords):
            print(json_dict["pagination"])
```

### Error Message

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
  File "C:\Users\New User\Desktop\path thing", line 43, in <module>
    json_dict = json.loads(line)
```

Comment: You should use `import json` specifically the `loads` or `load` method which intepret json as a python object, in this case a dict with a dict inside it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Oh hold on you are trying to use that module...but you should use it on the entire file content. Don't read lines of it, just pass the whole thing to loads

Comment: ive imported json already and i tried this 
cant figure out how to add code to a comment to ill put it on pastebin
https://pastebin.com/HwgCCmGC

Comment: Yeah, I realized after I made that first comment you had used the json module, had not looked beyond the readline part...in any case you now have essentially the same answer below that ChristiFati and I submitted at almost the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try to read each line, just use json.load on the entire file.

```
import json

with open(filePath, "r") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

total = data["pagination"]["total"]
print(total)
```